# Perl6-ish expression for the bits of an integer

Tags: raku

I've been trying to exercise my Perl 6 chops by looking at some golfing problems.  One of them involved extracting the bits of an integer.  I haven't been able to come up with a succinct way to write such an expression.

My "best" tries so far follow, using `2000` as the number.  I don't care whether the most or least significant bit comes first.

A numeric expression:

```
map { $_ % 2 }, (2000, * div 2 ... * == 0)
```

A recursive anonymous subroutine:

```
{ $_ ?? ($_ % 2, |&?BLOCK($_ div 2)) !! () }(2000)
```

Converting to a string:

```
2000.fmt('%b') ~~ m:g/./
```

Of these, the first feels cleanest to me, but it would be really nice to be able to generate the bits in a single step, rather than mapping over an intermediate list.

Is there a cleaner, shorter, and/or more idiomatic way to get the bits, using a single expression?  (That is, without writing a named function.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way would be:

```
2000.base(2).comb
```

The `.base` method returns a string representation, and `.comb` splits it into characters - similar to your third method.

Answer (score 4):

An imperative solution, least to most significant bit:

```
my $i = 2000; say (loop (; $i; $i +>= 1) { $i +& 1 })
```

The same thing rewritten using hyperoperators on a sequence:

```
say (2000, * +> 1 ...^ !*) >>+&>> 1
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative that is more useful when you need to change the base to anything above 36, is to use [`polymod`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/polymod) with an infinite list of that base.

Most of the time you will have to reverse the order though.

```perl6
say 2000.polymod(2 xx *);
# (0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1)
```

```perl6
say 2000.polymod(2 xx *).reverse;
say [R,] 2000.polymod(2 xx*);
# (1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0)
```